# How to use multiple textbox entries in part of a url in vb?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm making a visual basic program, and I'm trying to make a button go to a link, but two parts of the link need to come from text boxes. I know how to make it go to the url in the text box entry, but I need to know how to make it go to a preset url, only with two parts of the url coming from text box entries.

I tried ("example.com/test?ex="(TextBox1.Text)"?nl="(TextBox2.Text))

and that didn't work. Please help
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Process.Start("example.com/test?ex=" & TextBox1.Text & "?nl=" & TextBox2.Text)
```

Or, in Visual Studio 2015 you can use Interpolated Strings:

```
Process.Start($"example.com/test?ex={TextBox1.Text}?nl={TextBox2.Text}")
```

Comment: Thank you for concatenating with the ampersand.

Answer (score 2):

[`String.Format`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiqnZjnq-DNAhWGWh4KHffsBD8QFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.string.format(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNGkaslkGRifn8IB3dB65LLL7sDbYg&sig2=ab9H7DsBJwOM4QXodQZhjw&bvm=bv.126130881,d.cGc) version.

```
Process.Start(String.Format("example.com/test?ex={0}?nl={1}",TextBox1.Text,TextBox2.Text))
```